# Jdialog focus Issue when launched through C++(JNI)

Tags: java, c++, swing, java-native-interface, awt

I have a Java application which shows a modal parentless JDialog. This JDialog has couple of text fields. When I launch it standalone on win64, the focus comes on the JDialog correctly.
But when I am calling the launch function through my C++ application (JNI), it gets the focus technically but not practically. I have to click on the dialog to type in the text field. C++ code is calling following Java function:

```
public static bool launchApp(someVars){
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
     MyJDialog dialog = new MyJDialog(); 
     dialog.setVisible(true);
     ....
}
```

I tried catching the window events, but it correctly shows that WindowActivated and WindowOpened got called in both the cases (directly or through JNI). WindowDeactivated never got called.

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {                
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info("WindowListener method called: windowClosed.");
            }

            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info("WindowListener method called: windowOpened.");                                       
            }               

            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info("WindowListener method called: windowActivated.");
            }

            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info("WindowListener method called: windowDeactivated.");
            }

            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info("WindowFocusListener method called: windowGainedFocus.");
            }

            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info("WindowFocusListener method called: windowLostFocus.");
            }

            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                LOGGER.info(
                        "WindowStateListener method called: windowStateChanged."+ e);
            }
        });
```

Log shows following:

Jun 30, 2016 8:00:11 PM
INFO: WindowListener method called: windowActivated.

Jun 30, 2016 8:00:11 PM 
INFO: WindowListener method called: windowOpened.

This issue is reproducible on all windows versions except one Windows 10 system. I don't know what's different about that particular machine/installation.

Any clues?

Comment: `public static bool`? I think you're confusing the languages.

Comment: "*Any clues?*" Not without seeing a [mcve]. Post the C++ files that call the Java method too. We need to be able to click "Run" from Java, "Run" from C++ and see the different results.

Comment: confusing the languages...yeah..:)...but implementation is correct. this is just an example.

Comment: It's not a [mcve] though.

Comment: I agree. It would be a good amount of work to do that. will do it soon and upload. thanks for responding anyway.